# Material-ui's Switch component onChange handler is not firing

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've put some `Switch`es in an app and they work fine. Then I put the Switches in another app, but they don't work when clicked.

Both apps are using the same component. Here it is working in one app:

[image]

And here's the other app, not working:

[image]

In the second app, the `onChange` handler doesn't seem to ever fire.

The code in both apps looks like the following:

```
<Switch
  checked={(console.log('checked:', status === 'visible'), status === 'visible')}
  onChange={(e, c) => console.log('event:', e, c)}
/>
```

In the first app I see the output of those `console.log`s, while in the second app I only see the initial `console.log` of the `checked` prop, but I never see any of the `onChange` prop.

I checked if any ancestor elements have `click` handlers, and I didn't find any that are returning `false`, calling `stopPropagation`, or calling `preventDefault`.

Notice in the gif that when I click, the ripple effect still works, so click handling is obviously still working.

Any ideas why `onChange` may not be firing?

**UPDATE!** I replaced the switches with regular `<input type="checkbox">` elements, and it works great! See:

[image]

Looks to me like something is wrong with material-ui's `<Switch>` component. I have a hunch that I will investigate when I get a chance: there might be more than one `React` singleton in the application. I'll be back to post an update.

Comment: This might be a binding issue of the onChange handler. What does onChange do? Does it call a parent handler afterwards? It's very hard to know with the given code above.

Comment: Is there any click event handler on `Switch` parent component?

Comment: @HaiPham There isn't, and I tried to look all the way up to the root for click handlers. I found a few, but I don't see any that are returning false, calling preventDefault, or calling stopPropagation.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac `this.onChange` just does `console.log('on change')` but it never gets logged. I removed `this.onChange()`, so it just has a console.log directly in the attribute, but that is never called.

Comment: Did `console.log('event:', e, c)` fire on initalizing?

Comment: @HaiPham It never fired even once.

Comment: I would need to see more of the code around this component in the app where it isn't working. Try to create the simplest possible version of the non-working app that still demonstrates this problem. If that hasn't already pointed out the problem, share that in a CodeSandbox or similar.

Comment: @trusktr This component is the only thing in the app? Nothing else is being rendered around it?

Comment: @RyanCogswell The above example is literally all there is. I stick the switch in the second app, not doing anything special other than what you see, then when I click the switch, `onChange` is never fired. I have a thought: maybe I have more than one version of React in the application. I'm gonna test this out.

Comment: @RyanCogswell There's stuff rendered around it obviously, I'm sticking it inside other elements. However I double checked, and there are no `click` events that are stopping propagation or preventing default. In fact, I replaced the Switches with regular <input type="checkbox">` elements, and it works great. Something's wrong with material-ui's Switch.

Comment: @trusktr Just because none of the things you looked for were present doesn't mean that there isn't something about the elements around it causing a problem. Even if it is an issue with Switch, the issue is specific to some scenario you are causing in the app where it doesn't work. Until you know what that is, you don't know whether or not it is an issue with Switch.

Comment: @trusktr I recommend stripping out the elements being rendered around it until the problem goes away and see if you can isolate what causes it to not work.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I'll try that too. Thanks!

Comment: @trusktr Did this get resolved?

Comment: @VishrutReddi Unfortunately I set it aside and used native `input` check boxes.

Comment: @trusktr I see. I am currently hitting this so I was just wondering if you figured this out. I will report it here if I get around this or find a solution.

Comment: @VishrutReddi Thanks, that'd be great help for any one else who lands here. Here is the related GitHub issue: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/12866, but I've no idea how to make a simple reproduction, so it got closed.

Answer (score 7):

I think, this is a weird fix and it is working smoothly for me. So, instead of handleChange I am using handleClick. I am not using event here, instead I am passing a string which is obviously the name of the state or id in case of arrays.

```
<Switch
    checked={this.state.active}
    onClick={() => this.handleToggle('active')}
    value="active"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
/>

handleToggle = (name: string) => {
    this.setState({ active: !this.state.active });
};
```

I tried handleChange, but the problem still persists. I hope this will get fixed soon.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue with `Checkbox` and `Switch` in the **WordPress admin** area.

Turns out, there was **global CSS** rule like:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

Clicking the upper left corner of the element works, though.

As a solution, I reset some styles in my app root.

*EDIT:* Nevermind, I just put my whole app into **shadow DOM**. There are a few gotchas, I'll list them here:

1. You have to provide a [custom insertion point](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#insertionpoint) for Material-UI style elements inside the shadow DOM. In general, you have to make nothing gets put outside of you shadow DOM.
2. You have to load/link the font inside the shadow DOM and outside the shadow DOM (the light DOM).
3. Use `ScopedCssBaseline` instead of the global reset.
4. Dialogs have to have their `container` prop specified.

This is how I've set things up with Material-UI:

```
// configure-shadow-dom.js

import { create } from 'jss';
import { jssPreset } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const shadowHostId = 'my-app-root-id'

export const appRoot = document.createElement('div')
appRoot.setAttribute('id', 'app-root')

const styleInsertionPoint = document.createComment('jss-insertion-point')
export const jss = create({
    ...jssPreset(),
    insertionPoint: styleInsertionPoint,
})

const robotoFontLink = document.createElement('link')
robotoFontLink.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet')
robotoFontLink.setAttribute('href', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap')

const shadowHost = document.getElementById(shadowHostId)
shadowHost.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })

const shadowRoot = shadowHost.shadowRoot
shadowRoot.appendChild(robotoFontLink)
shadowRoot.appendChild(styleInsertionPoint)
shadowRoot.appendChild(appRoot)


// index.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ScopedCssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/ScopedCssBaseline';
import { StylesProvider } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import App from './App';
import { jss, appRoot } from './configure-shadow-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <StylesProvider jss={jss}>
            <ScopedCssBaseline>
                <App />
            </ScopedCssBaseline>
        </StylesProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    appRoot
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that in my case, there was a CSS in the page, something like

```css
.some-component { pointer-events: none; }
.some-component * { pointer-events: auto; }
```

where `.some-component` was containing my material-ui buttons and switches. I had to manually set `pointer-events` to `all` (or some value, I don't remember at at the moment) for the elements inside the switches.

So, that's one thing to look out for: check what `pointer-events` style is doing.

Answer (score 1):

in Switch component, changing onChange to onClick worked for me:

```
<Switch
    checked={this.state.active}
    onClick={() => this.handleToggle('active')}
    value="active"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

still running into similar issues getting an event from the switch. here's a quick fix using internal state (you should be using hooks now and functional components, if not you are missing out, but you can use `setState` to do what i'm showing here in a class component.)

```
const [switchChecked, setSwitchChecked] = useState(false);
```

.......

```
<Switch checked={switchChecked} onChange={() => {setSwitchChecked(!switchChecked);}}/>
```

you'll need to have a value for `switchChecked` in the components local state.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one checked or unchecked passed as a second argument.

````
<Switch
    checked={this.state.active}
    onClick={(e,flag) => this.handleToggle('active', flag)}
    value="active"
    inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'secondary checkbox' }}
/>```
````

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have to sniff the `checked` attribute from the event: `event.target.checked`

Full solution:

```
import { Switch } from '@material-ui/core';
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false);

  const switchHandler = (event) => {
    //THIS IS THE SOLUTION - use event.target.checked to get value of switch
    setChecked(event.target.checked);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Switch checked={checked} onChange={switchHandler} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This seems to break the default animation of the switch though - do you know why that is?

Comment: This also doesn't work for me. Only thing that made it work for me was using the click event instead and then I have to just toggle my own boolean state variable. Even then its buggy and seems to randomly not trigger the default animation properly. This component is buggy af

Answer (score 0):

After wasting 1 hour i get to know that switch is providing value at e.target.checked , which toggles upon click (true/false)

```
 const [taxIncluded, setTaxIncluded] =useState(false)
       const taxIncludeChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked, 'checked value here (true/false)');
  };
<Switch onChange={taxIncludeChange} value={taxIncluded} color="primary" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For my case the input dom was not giving proper size. It CSS was

```css
.css-rwip7p-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiSwitch-switchBase .MuiSwitch-input {
    left: -100%;
    width: 300%;
}
```

The wokaround hack for my case was to use inline style throug inputProps.

```html
    <Switch
      inputProps={{ style: {'height': '100%'} }}
      key={propertyName}
      checked={isGranted}
      value={propertyName}
      onChange={(e) => updateConsent(e)}
    />
```